# How do I know if there are any rows selected in my datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and the validationEngine plugin.

My issue is that I am only able to know which rows are selected on a particular page in the pagination. So, if I have rows selected on the second page of the pagination and no rows selected on the 1st page, it will show me an error 'Please select a row'.

I have read posts about it but not specific to my code, so that's the reason I am asking this question.

So in addition to the validation code I have, I should add the following code,

**CODE**

```
$("#mSelector").on("click", "button[name='next'],button[name='finish']",               
function() {
var $stepSelector = $(".WizardStep:visible"); // get current step               

 var anyError = false;                      
 $stepSelector .find("input,textarea,select").each(function () {
 if (!$(this).validationEngine('validate')) {// validate every input element inside this step
           anyError = true;
    }

 });

 if (anyError)
  return false; // exit if any error found
```

});

});

**CODE**

```
$(function () {
        var singleSelect =  $('.single-select').DataTable({
            'lengthMenu': ['300']
        });

        // Single row select
        $('.single-select tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                $('#hId').val('');
            } else {
                singleSelect.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#Id').val($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });

        var cId = $('#hdId').val();

        if (cId > 0) {
            $("#grid1.single-select")
                .find("[id='" + currentId + "']")
                .addClass('selected');
        }

        //selection
        var mGrid = $("#mSelector").DataTable({
            'lengthMenu': ['300']

        });
        $('#mSelector tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
                $('#mId').val('');

            } else {
                mGrid.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
                $('#mId').val($(this).attr('id'));
            } 

        });
```

**CODE**

```
$("button[name='next'],button[name='finish']").click(function() {
  var $step = $(".Step:visible"); // get current step

  var ifError = false;

  $step.find("input,textarea,select").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).validationEngine('validate')) { // validate 
      ifError = false;
    }
  });

  if (ifError)
    return false; // exit if there is an error
});
```

Comment: What do you use for row selection - [TableTools](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/select_multi.html) or the new [Select](http://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/multi.html) extension?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle for you code or live snippet?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com This is the code i am using for row selection,

Comment: @dsingh23, the code you've posted doesn't perform any row selection. You handle click on buttons and then validate inputs. Do you have buttons with names `text` and `finish` in the table itself? Please post your HTML as well or create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">$(function () { var singleSelect =  $('.single-select').DataTable({'lengthMenu': ['300'] });
 // Single row select datatable
$('.single-select tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
$('#hId').val('');
 } else {singleSelect.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('#hId').val($(this).attr('id'));}});
var cId = $('#hId').val();
if (cId > 0) {$("#grid.single-select")
.find("[id='" + currentId + "']")
.addClass('selected');}

Comment: var mGrid = $("#mSelector").DataTable({// selection
'lengthMenu': ['300']});
$('#miSelector tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {             
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
$('#mId').val('');                    
} else {mGrid.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('#mId').val($(this).attr('id')); } });`

Comment: @Gyrocode.com.., Yes I do have those buttons in the table itself. Its like a wizard. that's used for every table in the application. I have posted the code for row selection. I will try to create an example on jsfiddle as well.

Comment: Please avoid posting code in comments and update the question itself. Also clarify whether you have a problem with row selection or validation code above?

Comment: I have added the code in the question. The validation is working only for 1 page of the pagination. I have 10 pages in the pagination. So, if I have rows selected in the 2nd. 3rd, or any other page but not on the 1st or a current page, the validation shows me an error that no row is selected.

Comment: I don't know if it's the validationEngine plugin that's messing or is it the row selection that it is only taking into context one page of the pagination. It's hard for me to explain here but I am trying my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

DataTables removes non-visible rows from DOM for various reasons so when you attach an event handler it works for currently visible elements only.

> **SOLUTION**

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call.

Replace this code:

```js
$("button[name='next'],button[name='finish']").click(function() {
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

with

```js
$("#mSelector").on("click", "button[name='next'],button[name='finish']", function() {
   // ... skipped ...
});
```

where `mSelector` is your table ID.

From jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

Comment: I understand now how DataTables hide non-visible rows from DOM. I have added the code to my question. I want to know one more thing, since this is only for a particular table, whose tabel ID is: mSelector, i should be writing the code apart from the validation code that I am already using. Is that right?

Comment: I used the above code and it's still not working for me.

Comment: @dsingh23, make sure that buttons with name `next` and `finish` are in fact in table with id `mSelector`. Also you need to replace your code not add an additional function.

Comment: Those buttons are for every page. Every page has those buttons. And I need the number of rows only for that particular table. The button handlers are generic and not specific for the table. There are 2 scripts, one has the table and in the other one are the button handlers.

Comment: I tried the code in the script where the table is and it is not working for me.

Comment: @dsingh23, can you create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ with your full HTML and JS/CSS files and I will try to see where the problem is?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: there is a lot of dynamic code in my application and due to this reason I am unable to create an example on jsfiddle. Is there any other way out.

Comment: @dsingh23, I hope you can understand my solution, see my answer or [this article](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/). I cannot help more without seeing your code, you posted only snippets.  Visit your page, press `Ctrl+U` to view the source and paste your code into http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I have pasted the source code on pastebin. pleas take a look at it.

Comment: I apologize. I made it public now.

Comment: @dsingh23, yes, I looked at the code and buttons that you said were in the table, in fact are outside the table. I'm confused as to what the problem is.

Comment: the buttons are for every page in my website. I only need this row selection to work for my table. The validation code that I have posted works for every page in my website and validates every input. I only need this for one particular table. Since, it is taking into consideration only the rows selected on the current page.

Comment: the event delegation is not working at all for my code. It is not validating anything if I replace the code with the given solution.

Comment: @dsingh23, you're referring in your code to `.single-select` and `#mSelector` but these elements do not exist on the page, so that explains why row selection doesn't work. Obviously my answer is incorrect, so I would have to delete it.

Comment: Your answer perfectly works if the buttons are in the table. Is there a possible solution to this